# Find external email addresses in Google Groups for Business

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups

We have groups in our Google G Suite in which also members that do not have a domain account are registered. How can I search for them? It seems right now, that the only way is to check every group manually for their email address, which is a tedious process considering that we have 100+ groups.

For regular members (abc@ourorganization.com) I can just check their account which will list all group memberships.